# In Python, how do I test a function that makes asyncio.ensure_future(...) calls?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-asyncio, future

In python unit tests, how do I assert that a function was called if that function is called using asyncio.ensure_future(...)?  I have this simple test that fails:

```
async def test_assert_ensure_future_called():
    async def increment():
        increment.call_count += 1

    increment.call_count = 0

    asyncio.ensure_future(increment())
    asyncio.ensure_future(increment())
    asyncio.ensure_future(increment())

    # await asyncio.sleep(0)  # this allows the asyncio.ensure_future calls to run
    assert increment.call_count == 3  # this fails because the calls to increment() haven't happened yet
```

I found that if I insert a call like `await asyncio.sleep(0)` just before the assert statement, that the test will succeed.  I assume that this works because it deprioritizes the test task and lets the calls to increment go first.  Is this the proper way to do this in a test though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save references of those tasks and await it either calling `await` per tasks or using `asyncio.gather` for one-line.

```
import asyncio


async def test_assert_ensure_future_called():
    async def increment():
        increment.call_count += 1

    increment.call_count = 0


    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(increment()) for _ in range(3)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    assert increment.call_count == 3


asyncio.run(test_assert_ensure_future_called())
```

Comment: I didn't realize that ensure_future returns tasks that I can await.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use ```asyncio.create_task``` instead, which also return awaitable, and schedule task in event loop.

Comment: I use ensure_future because I want a "fire-and-forget" call.  Will create_task do the same thing?

Comment: Yes! Both works exactly same - only difference is: ```ensure_future``` being slightly low-level, According to this official [docoument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks).

Comment: `ensure_future` is more general, it's for converting any kind of awaitable object (valid target to `await`) into something that inherits `Future` and implements methods like `add_done_callback`. The use case for `ensure_future` is implementation of functions like `gather()` which accept awaitables, but need futures - they call `ensure_future`. If you know you're dealing with a coroutine, you can call `create_task`, which is what `ensure_future` will internally do when given a coroutine object. (The returned `Task` inherits from `Future`.) So yes, they're completely equivalent with coroutines.

Comment: Didn't know ```ensure_future``` support all 3 - coroutines, Tasks, and Futures - awaitables. Thanks!